# Set root .htaccess to selectively ignore subdomains/folders

Tags: apache, .htaccess, subdomain, root

I have a few different softwares on my server, and multiple subdomains. I'm using the typical LAMP stack, CentOS, Apache, MySQL, PHP, etc.

The problem is, a few particular folders could really do without having any .htaccess influence from the root, since it breaks some critical areas of the installations. Unfortunately, disabling `RewriteEngine` alone is not enough, as there is more to it that is affecting it.

This is what I want to do.

`.htaccess` in the root (I want this to remain in effect as it distributes some common things I want across most areas of my domain, but I want to be able to selectively be able to completely disable `.htaccess` from reaching certain subdomains/folders)

To be totally clear, I don't want to stop `.htaccess` from affecting other folders completely, I just want to be able to specify which ones it reaches, or the ones I don't want it to reach.

Answer (score 0):

You can either put an htaccess file in the folders you don't want mod_rewrite to do anything with with just the line:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

Or you can add some pass-throughs at the top of your rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?folder_to_ignore - [L]
RewriteRule ^/?another_to_ignore - [L]
```

Comment: That sort of fix doesn't work, unfortunately. I already tried. I was hoping there was something that would completely exempt certain folders from having any idea .htaccess exists anywhere. It's a type of software that doesn't require .htaccess and has a lot of its effects in place already, so .htaccess having any presence causes errors in some areas.